# U-SQL Error - Change the identifier to use at least one lower case letter

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I am fairly new to U-SQL and trying to run a U-SQL script in Azure Data Lake Analytics to process a parquet file using the Parquet extractor functionality. I am getting the below error and I don't find a way to get around it. 
Error - Change the identifier to use at least one lower case letter. If that is not possible, then escape that identifier (for example: '[ACTIVITY]'), or embed it in a CSHARP() block (e.g CSHARP(ACTIVITY)).

Unfortunately all the different fields generated in the Parquet file are capitalized and I don't want to to escape these identifiers. I have tried if I could wrap the identifier with CSHARP block and it fails as well (E_CSC_USER_RESERVEDKEYWORDASIDENTIFIER: Reserved keyword CSHARP is used as an identifier.)  Is there anyway I could extract the parquet file? Thanks for your help!
Code Snippet:

```
SET @@FeaturePreviews = "EnableParquetUdos:on";
```

@var1 =
    EXTRACT ACTIVITY string,
            AUTHOR_NAME string,
            AFFLIATION string

```
FROM "adl://xxx.azuredatalakestore.net/Abstracts/FY2018_028"
USING Extractors.Parquet();
```

@var2 =
     SELECT *
    FROM @var1 
    ORDER BY ACTIVITY ASC
    FETCH 5 ROWS;
OUTPUT @var2
TO "adl://xxx.azuredatalakestore.net/Results/AbstractsResults.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv();

Comment: Can you post a [clear, minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please?  I'm thinking a small U-SQL script and sample Parquet file which succinctly explains the problem.  That will be really useful and I'm sure someone will help you.

Comment: Yup, I should have done that. I added the snippet to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your description you try to say

```
EXTRACT ALLCAPSNAME int FROM "/data.parquet" USING Extractors.Parquet();
```

In U-SQL, we reserve all caps identifiers so we can add new keywords in the future without invalidating old scripts.

To work around, you just have to quote the name (escape it) like in any other SQL dialect:

```
EXTRACT [ALLCAPSNAME] int FROM "/data.parquet" USING Extractors.Parquet();
```

Note that this is not changing the name of the field. It is just the syntactic way to address the field.

Also note, that in most SQL communities, it is considered a best practice to always quote identifiers to avoid reserved keyword clashes.

If all fields in the Parquet file are all caps, you will have to quote them all... In a future update you will be able to say EXTRACT * FROM … for Parquet (and Orc) files, but you still will need to quote the columns when you refer to them explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs Michael, I tried to use the [ACTIVITY] in the select query and I get an error - the [ACTIVITY] doesn't exist in the Parquet file. I am pretty sure it exists in the file as I am using the Data Factory to do the CSV to Parquet conversion.

Comment: I will have the engineering team take a look if the quoted identifiers are supported correctly.

Comment: We did some tests and quoted identifiers work. Can you please provide me with a recent job link (within last 24 hours) so I can file an incident for further investigations? You can send me the information to usql at microsoft dot com.